# Unable to return NULL when character not found in the function xstrchr

Tags: c, null, return, c-strings, return-type

I am not able to make use of the `else` condition in `main()`. The code doesn't work when character is not found in string. How should I modify the `return` statement or the `else` condition in `main` ?

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *xstrchr(char *string, char ch);

void main() {
    char str[20], ch;
    printf("Enter a string :");
    gets(str);
    printf("Enter character to search in string :");
    scanf("%c", &ch);

    char *r = xstrchr(str, ch);
    printf("%c is stored at %d\n", *r, r);
    if (r != NULL)
        printf("Character '%c' found at %d index.\n", ch, (r - str + 1));
    else
        printf ("Character not found.");
}

char *xstrchr(char *s, char ch) {
    int flag = 0, i = 0;
    while (*(s + i) != '\0') {
        if (*(s + i) == ch) {
            flag = 1;
            return (s + i);
        }
        i++;
    }
    if (flag == 0) {
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

Comment: is it possible to get null with char?

Comment: `*(s + i)` should be written as `s[i]`. The `flag` variable is useless - it is always 0, except when set just before the `return`. `return` is not a function and doesn't require parentheses. `%d` cannot be used to print an address, use `%p`, use `size_t` as an index to strings, `main` must return `int`.

Comment: Never ***ever*** use `gets`!  It's a [dangerous function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used). Use e.g. [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) instead, but be aware of the differences between the functions.

Comment: "The code doesn't work" is no useful description of a problem. Please always tell us what you expect, what you get and what input you used for test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function **does** return `NULL` when the character is not found, but you have undefined behavior in `main()` when it does so as you dereference `r` in the `printf` statement before testing for a `NULL` result, causing your program to crash.

There are other problems:

- the prototype for `main` should be `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` or possibly `int main()`.
- you must nos use `gets()`. This function has been removed from the C language because it cannot be used safely. If the user types more than 19 characters at the prompt, your program will have undefined behavior as `gets()` will write beyond the end of the array.
- pointers should not be printed with `%d`, you should write:

  ```
  printf("%c is stored at %p\n", *r, (void *)r);
  ```
- the difference of 2 pointers has type `ptrdiff_t`, which mau be larger than `int` and should not be printed with `%d`. The standard format for this is `%td`, but many C libraries do not support this, so converting the difference to `int` may be preferable:

  ```
  printf("Character '%c' found at %d index.\n", ch, (int)(r - str + 1));
  ```
- index values start at `0` in C. It is confusing to refer to the first element of an array as index 1.
- you should test the return values of `fgets()` and `scanf()` to detect premature end of file or other input failures.
- index values may exceed the range of type `int`. You should use type `size_t` for `i` in `xstrchr()`.
- `flag` is not used in the `xstrchr` function: the update code and the test are redundant and can be removed.
- `*(s + i)` can be written `s[i]`, which is much more readable. Unless you are required to use the pointer arithmetic syntax explicitly, you should use the bracketed syntax.

Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *xstrchr(char *string, char ch);

int main() {
    char str[200], ch;
    printf("Enter a string: ");
    if (!fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin))
        return 1;
    printf("Enter character to search in string: ");
    if (scanf("%c", &ch) != 1)
        return 1;
    char *r = xstrchr(str, ch);
    if (r != NULL) {
        printf("Character '%c' found at %d index.\n", ch, (int)(r - str));
    else
        printf("Character not found.\n");
    return 0;
}

char *xstrchr(char *s, char ch) {
    size_t i = 0;
    while (s[i] != '\0') {
        if (s[i] == ch) {
            return s + i;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Finally, the `xstrchr()` function does not completely match the specification of the standard `strchr()` function:

- the argument type for `ch` is `int`, but its value is converted to `char` for comparison purposes.
- the argument type for `s` is `const char *` as the string is not modified by this function, but the return type is `char *` so the return value must then be cast as `(char *)`, which is an unfortunate but necessary step.
- the null terminator at the end of the string will be matched if `ch` has a null value.
- incrementing `s` instead of using an index variable is an alternative many C programmers would prefer.

Here is a modified version:

```
char *xstrchr(const char *s, int ch) {
    for (;; s++) {
        if (*s == (char)ch)
            return (char *)s;
        if (*s == '\0')
            return NULL;
    }
}
```